# Backup files to icloud in my react-native app

Tags: react-native, realm, icloud, cloudkit, realm-js

looking for react-native libraries or development approaches to archive the following:

#### My Use case

In my react-native app I want to sync pictures ( taken by users ) and other files like the user database "realm.db ( from realmjs )" with the user iCloud drive.

#### Question

Do I need to upload all the files with cloudkitjs to the web or is it possible to just place the files into a specific app directory and every time the user update the iphone device the -> app it will be automatically synced?

#### What I already tried

- activating iCloud support in my app
- created iCloud container

#### Requirements

- everything should be synced within the user/customer iCloud drive
- don't want to take care about GDPR guidelines
- only an iOS app exisits... no need to sync data between MacOS and iOS

#### My Stack

- react-native 0.60
- typescript

Many thanks for any help which put me into the right direction.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have pretty similar requirements and don’t want to use my own server/database. :)